# How to get rid of horizontal slide bar bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that is fixed to the stop and scrolls with content. Then I have some test content under the navbar.

Two div classes one is class jumbotron, the other is row. The content for some reason fits my screen with a small scroll bar and when you slide it you see there is like a 10px or so white gap. There is no gap in the navbar, just the body content.

Comment: are you putting your `.row` within a `.container`?  Please show us your code.

Comment: My code looks like absolute crap lol. Its just two separate divs, with no container, under body. I tried adding a custom container with width 100% but it didnt work.

Comment: Don't use a custom container just wrap your row in a div with `class="container"` or `class="container-fluid"`

Comment: That works to get rid of the horizontal slider,however now i have a gap of a few px on either side of my content, and the content is now centered. I want all content to be 100% screen width

Answer (score 1):

Rows must be wrapped in a `<div class="container">` or `<div class="container-fluid">`

This is explained in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

> Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or
>   `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Comment: Giving the body a .container fluid works to get rid of the horizontal scroll. However, now my content does not stretch the full width of the screen. There is a gap on either side of the content a few px wide. I would also like to note that when not giving a container of fluid, the content was full width of the screen, but the horizontal scroll only moved t the right, as the gap was only on the right side and not on both.

Comment: If you want to use the grid system then you need to fully know how it works.  Have you read the linked docs carefully?  Have you also tried using some developer tools (like the dev tools in chrome) to see what your layout is doing - where the margins and padding are, etc?

Answer (score -1):

If you're after a quick fix try adding this to your css

```
body,html{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: isnt it bad to do that?

Comment: "quick fixes" often are, you might also try putting your elements into divs with classes of .row or surrounding your page with a div with a class of .container. Failing that ensure you dont have any margins set that might cause problems

Comment: I added a custom container class with width 100% but that didnt do anything.

Comment: have you tried removing any margins/padding from the divs? or explicitly setting them to 0?

Comment: @dhutchinson Please don't do this. There is no need if you use bootstrap properly and will just add confusion/complexity.

Comment: I try not to change any css from the originial file, so i just create custom classes.